# Not able to render windbarb Highchart in angular

Tags: highcharts, angular5

I am trying to plot wind barb using my angular application. I used angular-highchart package but it's showing me below error -

Error: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Chart } from 'angular-highcharts';
import { MapChart } from 'angular-highcharts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <div [chart]="chart"></div>
`
})
export class AppComponent {
  chart = new Chart({
    title : { text : 'simple chart' },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      offset: 40      
    },
    series: [{
      type: 'windbarb',
      name:"Wind Direction",
      data: [
        [9.8, 177.9],
        [10.1, 177.2]
          ]             
    }, {
      type: 'area',  
      name:'WindSpeed',     
      data: [
        [9.8, 177.9],
        [10.1, 177.2]
       
    ],
  }]  
  });
 
  constructor() {
  }

    
    
}
```

here

Comment: Since you have error 17, following it's link can be useful. It says: `This error happens when you are setting chart.type or series.type to a series type that isn't defined in Highcharts. A typical reason may be that your are missing the extension file where the series type is defined, for example in order to run an arearange series you need to load the highcharts-more.js file.` Are you sure that you have included https://code.highcharts.com/modules/windbarb.js in your code? I guess that would be `import { windbarb } from 'angular-highcharts';` in angular terms.

Comment: We tried it but still facing a problem. can you please share me an example?

Comment: [ts] Module '"c:/Users/Akhese/windbarb/node_modules/angular-highcharts/angular-highcharts"' has no exported member 'windbarb'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check module.ts imports as per [angular-highcharts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highcharts) docs

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ChartModule, HIGHCHARTS_MODULES } from 'angular-highcharts';
import exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting.src';
import windbarb from 'highcharts/modules/windbarb.src';

export function highchartsModules() {
  // apply Highcharts Modules to this array
  return [ exporting,windbarb ];
}

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule,ChartModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  providers: [
    { provide: HIGHCHARTS_MODULES, useFactory: highchartsModules } // add as factory to your providers
  ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-windbarb-highcharts?embed=1&file=app/app.module.ts) demo

Comment: Thanks you stackblitz